# How could I get the __call__ instance's attached?

Tags: python

```
 class Method(object):
     def __call__(self):
         #how could I get the App instance here?
         return True

 class App(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.g = Method()
```

As you can see, the above code can explain my question.

Comment: What is `self` in the last line supposed to refer to?

Comment: @SvenMarnach sorry for my mistake. I have updated the question.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?  There's too little context in the question to tell what the best option is.

Comment: I think, whatever you are trying to achieve, you are doing it wrong. Let me guess, you have a C++ background and you want to make a functor.

Comment: @StefanoBorini no, I'm not a c++ programer. I'm just want to approach an client of server method, it is an HTTP server.My client has many remote server apis request ,Therefor my Method class have to implement this http request's abstract.

Comment: @Dreampuf: so you want to monkey patch the methods to implement a different access strategy? I don't get it. Why can't you use a strategy pattern ?

Comment: @StefanoBorini Actually, the above code is my strategy pattern implement,And the Method class is method factory, it's encapsulated of many a little different api's invoke.

Comment: @StefanoBorini can you tell me more detail of this implement about aspect of wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to store a pointer back to the App object in the Method:

```
class Method(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self):
        self.app.something()
        return True

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.g = Method(self)
```

If you have an absolute need to avoid passing the `self` pointer in App, you'll need to inspect the stack to retrieve it instead.

**The following is discouraged and only works when you instantiate `Method` objects in a method of `App`**:

```
import sys

class Method(object):
    def __init__(self):
        parent = sys._getframe(1) # Calling context
        locals_ = frame.f_locals
        assert ('self' in locals_,
            'Method objects can only be instanciated inside instance methods')
        self.app = locals_['self']
```

Comment: This will create a something similar to a "bound method" for each instance.  It might be better to use descriptors for this, so we only need a single instance for the class, and "bound methods" are only created when necessary.  I'm waiting for the OP's answer to my comment.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I agree, but it may be too sophisticated for the use case. As usual, too little context.

Comment: could I don't pass the app instance ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters how? I'd would like see it.

Comment: +1 after the OP's edit to the question.  And agreed, too little context.